# Why is my preferences data being returned as an array instead of a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, oop, data-conversion

I'm using this Config class to make it easier for me to read out my prefs.

```
<?php

class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if ($path){
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit]; 
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, I should be able to get a config by using this line in my scripts:

```
echo Config::get('settings/main_color');
```

My preferences are in a JSON file, but the array that is stored in $GLOBALS['config'] looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [mysql] => Array ( 
        [host] => localhost:3307 
        [username] => root 
        [password] => usbw 
        [db] => webshop )
    [remember] => Array ( 
        [cookie_name] => hash 
        [cookie_expiry] => 604800 ) 
        [sessions] => Array ( 
        [session_name] => user 
        [token_name] => token ) 
    [settings] => Array ( 
        [main_color] => #069CDE 
        [front_page_cat] => Best Verkocht,Populaire Producten 
        [title_block_first] => GRATIS verzending van €50,- 
        [title_block_second] => Vandaag besteld morgen in huis! ) 
    [statics] => Array ( 
        [header] => enabled 
        [title_block] => enabled 
        [menu] => enabled 
        [slideshow] => enabled 
        [left_box] => enabled 
        [email_block] => enabled 
        [footer] => enabled 
        [keurmerken] => enabled 
        [copyright] => enabled ) 
)
```

Now, when I try to reach a pref in my scripts. It says that my string is an array. So I used print_r to display the array. Then the following is the outcome:

> print_r(Config::get('settings/main_color'));
>
> Array ( [header] => enabled [title_block] => enabled [menu] => enabled [slideshow] => enabled [left_box] => enabled [email_block] => enabled [footer] => enabled [keurmerken] => enabled [copyright] => enabled )

Where have I made a mistake in my scripts?

Comment: check your get method, definitely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If truly, your array is structured, as shown above, this should work

```
<?php

class Config {
public static function get($path = null) {
    if ($path){
        $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
        $path = explode('/', $path);

        $parent = $path[0];
        $child = $path[1];

        if(isset($config[$parent][$child])) {
            $config = $config[$parent][$child]; 
        }

        return $config;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Hope it Helps.